Using libXi with Vcpkg
I am trying to make a C project with libXi as a dependency to control mouse movements across the linux system (not just in 1 window) . I am trying to use Vcpkg and followed the following tutorial Install and use packages with CMake in Visual Studio Code. I have replaced fmt with libxi as vcpkg add port libxi
currently my CMake file looks like this: -
# project_root/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
message("The c version is ${CMAKE_C_STANDARD}, using the ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} compiler")

project(prj C)
find_package(libxi CONFIG REQUIRED)
    
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/"
)

target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE libxi)

when running cmake with the default preset it gives the error
CMake Error at /home/username/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:853 (_find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libxi" with any of
  the following names:

    libxiConfig.cmake
    libxi-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libxi" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "libxi_DIR" to
  a directory containing one of the above files.  If "libxi" provides a separate
  development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)

what can i do in this situation?
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with gcc-10

there is already a libxi port in vcpkg but you probably want to use the system one (which you'll get unless you set X_VCPKG_FORCE_VCPKG_X_LIBRARIES to ON in a triplet). Those typical linux xorg libraries are consumed via FindPkgConfig.cmake
